# Обработка ввода и клика в WM_COMMAND

Tags: c++, winapi, button, edit

После запуска ни на что не реагирует.

```
HWND CheckButton;
static HWND RealEdit,ImEdit;
    RealEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "edit", "0", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT,
                210, 20, 51, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)101, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
ImEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "edit", "0", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT,
                210, 50, 51, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)110, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
CheckButton = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("button"), TEXT("Ответить"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            170, 80, 91, 23,
            hwnd, (HMENU)1000, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);

case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 101 && LOWORD(wParam) == 101) //Что-то написал в эти edit`ы
        {
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1000) //Нажал на кнопку
            {
                char p[123];
                char d[123];
                GetWindowText(RealEdit, p, 5);
                GetWindowText(ImEdit, d, 5);
                double a = atoi(p); //ТО что ввел юзер
                double b = atoi(d);
                if (temp.GetReal() == a && temp.GetIm() == b) //Если правильно то правильно, если нет, то нет
                {
                    MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Good"), TEXT("Good"), 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Bad"), TEXT("Good"), 0);
                }

            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Вы уже разобрались с неинициализированными переменными в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942233/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-edit-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-char ?

Comment: Да, нужно было объявить как static.